# What does $f$ in one-to-one correspondence with $A$(Domain) mean?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am studying Charles Pinter's Set Theory and am trying to solve the following question.
Let $f:A \to B$ be a function. Prove that $f$ is in one-to-one correspondence with $A$.

From what I know, I have learned that if $f$ is bijective, we can say $A$ is in one-to-one correspondence with $B$. But what does it mean for the function $f$ itself to be in one-to-one correspondence with $A$?

I have set up $f$ as a set: $f=\{(x,y):x \in A , y \in B\}$

And I let $g$ be a function such that $g:f \to A$. Am I on the right track?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

I tried to prove the injective part, but am not sure about it. Here is how it went.

Let $((x_1,y_1),x) \in g$ and $((x_1,y_2),x) \in g$

Since $f$ is a function, $(x_1,y_1)=(x_1,y_2)$.
Thus $g$ is injective.

I also have no clue on how to show the surjective part. Would I show that
$A \subset ranf$?

Comment: Your set $f$, as you've written it, is just the set $A \times B$, which is probably not in 1-1 correspondence with $A$. Try $f = \{ (x, f(x)): x \in A \}$. Then the natural map to consider is $g: A \to f$ with $g(x) = (x,f(x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track, but you need to actually define that function $g$. That is, you need to specify $g((x,y)) = ?$

However, there is an obvious choice here:  $g((x,y)) = x$

To prove $g$ is injective, you do pretty much what you did:

Assume $((x_1,y_1),x) \in g$ and $((x_2,y_2),x) \in g$. Because of how we defined $g$, it must be the case that $x_1=x$ and $x_2=x$, and thus $x_1=x_2$. Since $(x_1,y_1) \in f$ and $(x_2,y_2) \in f$, we thus get that $(x_1,y_1) \in f$ and $(x_1,y_2) \in f$. But since $f$ is a function, we get that $y_1 = y_2$, and thus $(x_1,y_1) = (x_2,y_2)$. Thus, $g$ is injective.

To prove surjectivity: for any $x \in A$, we know that $g((x,f(x)) = x$. So yes, for all $x \in A$ there is some $y$ (namely $f(x)$) such that $g(y) = x$. Thus, $g$ is surjective.